# Invalid cursor state from SQLSetPos

Tags: odbc, recordset

ALL,

```
ret = SQLForeignKeys( stmt_fk, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, catalogName, SQL_NTS, schemaName, SQL_NTS, tableName, SQL_NTS );
if( ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
{
    // error handling
}
bool fkFound = false;
for( ret = SQLFetch( stmt_fk ); ( ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO ) && ret != SQL_NO_DATA; ret = SQLFetch( stmt_fk ) )
{
    fkFound = true;
}
if( ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO && ret != SQL_NO_DATA )
{
    // error handling
}
else if( fkFound )
{
    ret = SQLSetPos( stmt_fk, 0, SQL_POSITION, SQL_LOCK_NO_CHANGE );
    if( ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
    {
    }
    else
    {
        // row processing
    }
```

In here calling SQLSetPos() returns an error "Invalid cursor state".
An ODBC API does not have a function to reset the statement handle and set the cursor to the record 1 in the recordset, so I presume I should use this one, but it fails.

How do I fix it? Or maybe there is an alternative way of doing what I want?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

The [ODBC API docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlsetpos-function?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) that this error results when --

> - The *`StatementHandle`* was in an executed state, but no result set was associated with the *`StatementHandle`*.
> - (DM) A cursor was open on the *`StatementHandle`*, but **`SQLFetch`** or **`SQLFetchScroll`** had not been called.
> - A cursor was open on the *`StatementHandle`*, and **`SQLFetch`** or **`SQLFetchScroll`** had been called, but the cursor was positioned before the start of the result set or after the end of the result set.
> - The argument *`Operation`* was `SQL_DELETE`, `SQL_REFRESH`, or `SQL_UPDATE`, and the cursor was positioned before the start of the result set or after the end of the result set.

Based on that, I'm betting there was an unnoticed (possibly silent) preceding error, which is what really needs to be addressed.  I suggest reviewing a complete ODBC Trace of the run to this point.